# Emulator uses too much ram

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've just installed the Android SDK and create my AVD, but I've got a problem.
I'm on a Windows 7 x64, with an Intel i5 and 4GB RAM, so the emulator should run well.

But when I start it, on the windows task manager, I can see that it use more than 1GB of RAM!
Is it possible?!

I tried to use snapshot, tried to set the device ram size to 1024 and tried to remove the SD emulation, as adviced in other question like this, but nothing changes.

Should I try to remove some SDK? Because I've installed a lot of them, for try to launch app in some different devices... but if them are going to slow me down, I'll just keep the 2.2 and 3.0 and no other else...
Or maybe I shoud try to run in a x86 system?

Thanks!

Comment: 1gb ram for a emulator is big, try to reduce it to 512...

Comment: *"tried to set the device ram size to 1024"* - Pretty sure the RAM size spec. is in MB, i.e., 1GB.

Comment: I am on 32 bit MS Vista with 4 gig ram and no problems. just as many sdk addons as you have too. What other stuff is running? Usually Eclipse is the highest, Chrome is 2nd and than the android emulator is down at 600 meg or lower ram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing that can be helpful (since I saw you were mentioning speed as well) is to lower the resolution of the emulator. At the Google IO 2011 session on the developer tools (video at http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-development-tools.html), they claimed that the reason the emulator is so slow is actually the graphics, not the CPU emulation, and that a lower resolution will help significantly. Hopefully things will speed up in the future, since they are working on hardware-accelerating the emulator! Obviously you're going to have to test on higher resolutions at some point, but you can try and get as much development done as possible on a lower setting.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the amount of RAM your emulator uses. Delete your current emulator and create a new one. If you're using eclipse to develop your app click on the Android button. Delete your current emulator and then create a new one. Under the heading SD Card you can set the size of your emulator.

Comment: Well, deleting and creating a new one I solved the problem of too much ram used. But it's still incredibly slow...